# How to create or delete a folder on the Unix machine using Ant task which runs on Windows machine

Tags: ant, directory

I need to delete a directory in Unix and create a new one.

All should be part of Ant task in Windows machine

Comment: @Vishu: how are you connecting to the unix box?

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth it to try it this way as I am not 100% sure if you can actually script a logging in, security implications otherwise, your password would be exposable...so I have not really done this before by using `putty -m` using the script in place.

```
putty host -l login_name -pw password -m my_script
```

`my_script` would contain

```
rmdir some_directory_name
```

The other way I can think of it is to use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/), which is a BASIC like syntax and to automate the process of logging on, and feeding a `rmdir directory_name`, perhaps to make it more flexible, supply the host, user id, password and the directory name to the autoit script which, can by the way be compiled to a standalone program...

Comment: Thanks for ur response.But i need to do everything it from ANT build,
so can u please tell me how to write ANT target for that

Answer (score 1):

I used [SSHEXEC](http://ant.apache.org/manual/OptionalTasks/sshexec.html) to create and delete directory on remote unix machine.I just return shell script to create and delete directory and run that using sshexec.
Same thing we can do using FTP,But i dont have access to ftp so i used sshexec its working good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SSHExec documentation: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html